# How to install glib and mdbtools on Ubuntu?

Tags: glib

I'm trying to install mdbtools on my ubuntu9.10.   When running the ./configure for the mdbtools, the script runs into problems and terminates with the following message:

```
checking for GLIB - version >= 2.0.0... 
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.22.0, but GLIB (2.22.3)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
```

How do I resolve this issue and get the mdbtools' ./configure to run properly?  How do I know if pkg-config is correct?  What are the steps to determine the correct value for LD_LIBRARY_PATH?  What are the steps to determine the correct value for PKG_CONFIG_PATH?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I just had to do a

sudo apt-get install mdbtools

to install the mdbtools